# Binding multible dropdown lists from one source

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net, vb.net

I have multiple drop down lists that I want to fill with the same items.

The following code will fill only the first DropDownList in the code (DropDownList1) and will not fill any of the others. For testing, I moved "DropDownList3" to be first in code to see what would happen and then only "DropDownList3" Filled with correct data. What do I need to do to make then all fill with the same data?

```
con.Open()
cmd1 = New SqlCommand(SqlQuery & SqlQuery2, con)
dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader

DropDownList1.DataSource = dr1
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "FullInfo"
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "FullInfo"
DropDownList1.DataBind()

DropDownList3.DataSource = dr1
DropDownList3.DataTextField = "FullInfo"
DropDownList3.DataValueField = "FullInfo"
DropDownList3.DataBind()

DropDownList4.DataSource = dr1
DropDownList4.DataTextField = "FullInfo"
DropDownList4.DataValueField = "FullInfo"
DropDownList4.DataBind()

DropDownList5.DataSource = dr1
DropDownList5.DataTextField = "FullInfo"
DropDownList5.DataValueField = "FullInfo"
DropDownList5.DataBind()

DropDownList6.DataSource = dr1
DropDownList6.DataTextField = "FullInfo"
DropDownList6.DataValueField = "FullInfo"
DropDownList6.DataBind()

DropDownList7.DataSource = dr1
DropDownList7.DataTextField = "FullInfo"
DropDownList7.DataValueField = "FullInfo"
DropDownList7.DataBind()
con.Close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fill a `DataTable` and reuse that as a source.

```
Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable

Dim connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connStr)
Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(SqlQuery & SqlQuery2, connection)

adapter.Fill(dt)

DropDownList1.DataSource = dt
DropDownList2.DataSource = dt
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer got me to the right place. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

```
private sub BindDrops(byRef drop as dropdownlist, byval text as string, byval value as string)

    con.Open()
    cmd1 = New SqlCommand(SqlQuery & SqlQuery2, con)
    dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader
    con.close()

    drop.DataSource = dr1
    drop.DataTextField = text
    drop.DataValueField = value
    drop.databind()
    end sub
```

The query needs to return a text and a value:
i.e:
query = "SELECT ID_FIELD, NAME_FIELD FROM..."

```
BindDrops(DropDownList1, "NAME_FIELD","ID_FIELD")
BindDrops(DropDownList2, "NAME_FIELD","ID_FIELD")
...
BindDrops(DropDownListN, "NAME_FIELD","ID_FIELD")
```